# SQL Can I have an IN or CONTAINS in the JOIN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am joining two SQL tables and I want to do something like this

```
LEFT JOIN uscities Ci 
        ON Customer_State = ci.state_id
        -- and Customer_City = ci.city
        and Customer_Zip in ci.zips
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: You need subquery. `and Customer_Zip in (select zips from ci)`

Comment: Why isn't that just another `JOIN` criteria? `and Customer_Zip = ci.zips`?

Comment: @EricBrandt Customer_Zip looks like '11000' and ci.zips looks like '11000 110001 11002...'

Comment: Try it with the subquery and I'll bet you get thousands more rows than you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `IN` in a `JOIN` clause.  In fact, you can have *any* operator you want.

However, you cannot use `IN` on a single field.  In fact, you simply should not be storing lists of things inside a string.  It is very bad data modeling.  You should have a separate table with one row per zip and per entity.  That is the SQLish way to do things.

That said, I would recommend `string_split()`:

```
LEFT JOIN uscities Ci 
ON c.Customer_State = ci.state_id AND
   c.Customer_Zip IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(ci.zips, ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ci.zips` is a concatenated string of all zips, you **can** look inside it with the clause:

```
and CHARINDEX(Customer_Zip, ci.zips) > 0
AND Len(Customer_Zip) = 5
```

However, this is a very inefficient action in SQL Server. It would be much better for you to split out this list of zip codes into a `ZipCode` table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE ZipCodes (
    ZipCode char(5) PRIMARY KEY
    )
```

Then, your condition is like:

```
and EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ZipCodes
    WHERE Customer_Zip = ZipCode
    )
```

More efficient, overall faster.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated here, you can essentially have *any* operator in a `JOIN ON` clause expression. You just have to be careful that the join expression only matches a single row of each item (table) being joined.

Having the `ci.zips` element be a string of space-separated zipcodes complicates things, but you can still search for (match) a specific customer zipcode within it with a simple `LIKE` clause:

```
left join uscities as ci
    on Customer_State = ci.state_id
--  and Customer_City = ci.city
    and ci.zips like '%' + Customer_Zip + '%'
```

If the `ci.zips` string is very long, though, this may not be that efficient.